# Extra Tabs in Input Fields after retrieving from Db

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from the db in an input field through PHP. Instead of the placeholder, I want to display this retrieved value in the input field if the data exists. I am able to retrieve the data from the db, but it is adding few extra tabs before the actual input.

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title"  value="
<?php  
    $title='title';
    $clean = trim(retrieve_project_info($email,$title));
    echo $clean;
?>">
```

So, if the input in the db is 'coldplay'. the retrieved data looks like '[tab][tab][tab]coldplay' and the url has many %09s in it.

I have removed whitespaces by using the trim method. But, trim does not remove tabs. 
Any idea how to remove these tabs?

Comment: You have whitespace between `value="` and `<?php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, removing tabs is easy, but you better find out why they are there instead of removing them.
But your code:

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title"  value="
<?php  
    $title='title';
    $clean = trim(retrieve_project_info($email,$title));
    echo $clean;
?>">
```

would be better written like this:

```
<?php  
    $title='title';
    $clean = trim(retrieve_project_info($email,$title));    
?>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title"  value="<?php echo $clean; ?>">
```

Does that help removing your tabs?
The reason I suggest this is because retrieve_project_info could output the tabs.

One more observation: If $clean contains " will your code fail?

EDIT: @palmi

This is how I do it:

```
function doFormSafeHTMLEncode($someStr){
    return htmlspecialchars($someStr,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); 
}
```

And I call that function everywhere where I output raw code to a formfield.

Comment: One could even use the [shortcut](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) `<?=$clean?>` instead of `<?php echo $clean; ?>`, or of course just go directly for `<?=trim(retrieve_project_info($email,'title'))?>`.

Comment: Don't do that. Short_open_tags are not enabled everywhere. (eg, not on my servers. ;-) )

Comment: Thanks a Lot. The issue was that i was adding a lot of space in value="" before echoing out the value in PHP. And Yes, you were right. Adding a double quote in the field in the db fails this code. Any idea how to bypass that?. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Follow the link in my comment: `<?=` is always available in PHP versions >= 5.4.

Comment: @palmi: Yes, escape the code. I'll edit my original posting because I cannot really format in this commentbox

Comment: @eggyal: Isn't that what I said? It is not enabled everywhere. Personally I don't like relying on such constructs if with a few keystrokes more you can create code that runs everywhere.

Comment: Fair enough, but then one will always be restricted to coding for v1 of every language (and, at that, one assumes every future version is backward-compatible).  At some point the benefit of dropping support for earlier versions outweighs the costs of so doing, but that judgement is best left to you and the specific requirements of your application.

Comment: @eggyal: In this case there is no reason at all to expect that support for <?php echo ... ?> will ever be dropped. It is not deprecated or something. I wouldn't advise making a habbit of it if you prefer your code portable. (Of course, if you don't want to port it, use the shorthand if you prefer.)

Answer (score 0):

Take out the tabs in your code and put it to the chrome of the screen. I did and it works for me. Even though it is great to have readable code, however this method works for now until i find another solution.